# How to get user's age category inside an iOS app?

Tags: ios, app-store

The Apple App Store has some fairly strict requirements on what content an app can display and still meet the age ratings.  I'd like to add a feature that can display content created by any 3rd party which means that, though "adult content" is not appropriate, it's not possible to guarantee that some spammer or vulgar person doesn't post inappropriate things.

I'm considering blocking access to that particular feature of the program for younger users.

*How can an iOS app determine the age "category" of its user in order to choose what features to provide*?

Other suggestions on how to deal with the issue of un-vetted 3rd party content is also welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Ok so basically you want to know if there is a way to detect the users age and thus display certain features as is appropriate.

Well two ideas come to mind:

**IDEA 1**
You could try using the built in contacts API to see which contact the user has set themself as. If they have one, then check if it has a birth date. And thus figure out their age.

**IDEA 2**
Ask the user to enter their birth date in when they launch the app for the very first time. Then figure out the age and save it in a NSUserDefault. You can then use that value throughout the app to determine what features and posts to show the user.